# Unable to connect to phpMyAdmin on raspberry pi after rebooting

Tags: python, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi

I've had a database set up in mysql and was using phpmyadmin to host. Everything was working great until I decided to reboot my pi.

I was in the process of trying to get a mysql library to import into a python file but it was giving an error. So I followed a few stackoverflow pages and I ran a few commands to "download packages" :

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-mysql.connector 
sudo python -m pipinstall mysql-connector 
sudo apt install python3-mysql.connector
```

They actually didn't help me get mysql.connector imported at all so that's great.

Searching stackoverflow said to reboot so I did, and when I came back to try to connect to phpmyadmin, I had a bunch of errors.
[image]

I'm honestly so stuck and feeling really helpless. I have no idea why it would not let me connect to the database anymore. I don't know if it was through the commands I ran (which didn't really do anything considering I already had

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. It would be a huge help.

Comment: phpmyadmin is a program written in php, to administer a mysql database, so you really don't connect to phpmyadmin, you connect to the database. First check if the mysql database is runnig you in other words did mysql start as service, you can try ti start it manually you to see what happens

Comment: So if I go to terminal, type in \r for reconnect to server, and it says `current database: **NONE**` thats a bad sign right? I created the database on phpmyadmin so I'm not familiar with how to start it manually

Comment: try sudo service mysql restart

Comment: I don;t think anything's changed. I checked the same command and checked my acsess to phpmyadmin @nbk

Comment: look with `ps` if the process is running, i think you should try your luck, with people who do much more linux than me. I voted to send you to DBA